# Crop an image in imagebox control and save it

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, crop

What I am doing is making a program that designs a card and displays the image real-time. I have finished that part and it works perfectly fine. Now i need to crop the image and save as the way its saving atm which has 2 white bars at the top and bottom. This is the code that I am using now for saving.

```
        private void SaveCardbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open the saveFileDialog
            if (saveWork.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                CardImg.Image.Save(saveWork.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: the question is how do i crop the image then save it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already posted this answer in asp .net forum.
Please try this one -

The following crop function will accept 4 parameters:

1. `Width`: This will be the width of cropped image.
2. `Height`: This will be the height of cropped image.
3. `Source Image File Path`: This will be the full path of the source image file.
4. `Save Cropped Image File Path`: This will be the full path of the save cropped image file.

   ```
   public static void CropImage(int Width, int Height, string sourceFilePath, string saveFilePath) {
   // variable for percentage resize 
   float percentageResize = 0;
   float percentageResizeW = 0;
   float percentageResizeH = 0;

   // variables for the dimension of source and cropped image 
   int sourceX = 0;
   int sourceY = 0;
   int destX = 0;
   int destY = 0;

   // Create a bitmap object file from source file 
   Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap(sourceFilePath);

   // Set the source dimension to the variables 
   int sourceWidth = sourceImage.Width;
   int sourceHeight = sourceImage.Height;

   // Calculate the percentage resize 
   percentageResizeW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
   percentageResizeH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);

   // Checking the resize percentage 
   if (percentageResizeH < percentageResizeW) {
       percentageResize = percentageResizeW;
       destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height - (sourceHeight * percentageResize)) / 2);
   } else {
       percentageResize = percentageResizeH;
       destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width - (sourceWidth * percentageResize)) / 2);
   }

   // Set the new cropped percentage image
   int destWidth = (int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * percentageResize);
   int destHeight = (int)Math.Round(sourceHeight * percentageResize);

   // Create the image object 
   using (Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height)) {
       objBitmap.SetResolution(sourceImage.HorizontalResolution, sourceImage.VerticalResolution);
       using (Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap)) {
           // Set the graphic format for better result cropping 
           objGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
           objGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
           objGraphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight), new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

           // Save the file path, note we use png format to support png file 
           objBitmap.Save(saveFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Call the above `CropImage` method by using following code:

```
CropImage(100, 100, "c://destinationimage.jpg", "c://newcroppedimage.jpg");
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: this worked great thanks just wish i could get it to work with the imagebox

Answer (score 2):

i use this code to do image cropping. Please note that pbOriginalImage is your picture box that has the image.

```
       private void pbOriginalImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Starting point of the selection:
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _selecting = true;
                _selection = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationExceptions.HandleAppExc(ex);
        }
    }

    private void pbOriginalImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Update the actual size of the selection:
            if (_selecting)
            {
                _selection.Width = e.X - _selection.X;
                _selection.Height = e.Y - _selection.Y;

                // Redraw the picturebox:
                pbOriginalImage.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationExceptions.HandleAppExc(ex);
        }

    }

    private void pbOriginalImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (pbOriginalImage.Image == null)
                return;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _selecting)
            {
                // check selection rectangle has non-zero Height and Width
                if (!ValidateSelection(_selection))
                {
                    _selecting = false;

                    return;
                }

                // Check that selection rectangle does extend outside of image boundaries
                ValidateRectangleSize();

                // Create cropped image:
                Image tempImage = pbOriginalImage.Image.Clone() as Image;
                Image img = tempImage.Crop(_selection);



                // Fit image to the picturebox:
                profileImage.Image = img.Fit2PictureBox(profileImage);
                _selecting = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationExceptions.HandleAppExc(ex);
        }

    }

    private void pbOriginalImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_selecting)
            {
                // Draw a rectangle displaying the current selection
                Pen pen = Pens.GreenYellow;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _selection);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationExceptions.HandleAppExc(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void commandBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|bmp Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);

                    if (file.Length == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBoxEx.Show("Invalid image. Please select valid image.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (file.Length > 2097152)
                    {
                        MessageBoxEx.Show("Image size cannot exceed 2MB.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        return;
                    }
                    textProfileImagePath.Text = dlg.FileName;
                    pbOriginalImage.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName).Fit2PictureBox(pbOriginalImage);
                    profileImage.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName).Fit2PictureBox(profileImage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Out of memory"))
            {
                MessageBoxEx.Show("Invalid image. Please select valid image.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
                ApplicationExceptions.HandleAppExc(ex);
        }
    }

    // Check that selection rectangle does extend outside of image boundaries
    private void ValidateRectangleSize()
    {
        Size imgSize = this.pbOriginalImage.Image.Size;
        int selectionWidth;
        int selectionHeight;

        // check width
        if (_selection.X < 0)
        {
            _selection.X = 0;
        }

        selectionWidth = _selection.Width + _selection.X;
        if (selectionWidth > imgSize.Width)
        {
            _selection.Width = imgSize.Width - _selection.X - 1;
        }

        // check height
        if (_selection.Y < 0)
        {
            _selection.Y = 0;
        }

        selectionHeight = _selection.Height + _selection.Y;
        if (selectionHeight > imgSize.Height)
        {
            _selection.Height = imgSize.Height - _selection.Y - 1;
        }
    }

    // check selection rectangle has non-zero Height and Width
    private bool ValidateSelection(Rectangle selection)
    {
        // routine to validate the selection
        if (selection.Width <= 0 || selection.Height <= 0)
        {
            // if you get here a good rectangle was not created
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and this is the extension class i use.

```
     public static class ImageExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Crops an image according to a selection rectangel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">
    /// the image to be cropped
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="selection">
    /// the selection
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// cropped image
    /// </returns>
    public static Image Crop(this Image image, Rectangle selection)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = image as Bitmap;

        // Check if it is a bitmap:
        if (bmp == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid image (Bitmap)");

        // Crop the image:
        Bitmap cropBmp = bmp.Clone(selection, bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Release the resources:
        image.Dispose();

        return cropBmp;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Fits an image to the size of a picturebox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">
    /// image to be fit
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="picBox">
    /// picturebox in that the image should fit
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// fitted image
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Although the picturebox has the SizeMode-property that offers
    /// the same functionality an OutOfMemory-Exception is thrown
    /// when assigning images to a picturebox several times.
    /// 
    /// AFAIK the SizeMode is designed for assigning an image to
    /// picturebox only once.
    /// </remarks>
    public static Image Fit2PictureBox(this Image image, PictureBox picBox)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Graphics g;

        // Scale:
        double scaleY = (double)image.Width / picBox.Width;
        double scaleX = (double)image.Height / picBox.Height;
        double scale = scaleY < scaleX ? scaleX : scaleY;

        // Create new bitmap:
        bmp = new Bitmap(
            (int)((double)image.Width / scale),
            (int)((double)image.Height / scale));

        // Set resolution of the new image:
        bmp.SetResolution(
            image.HorizontalResolution,
            image.VerticalResolution);

        // Create graphics:
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        // Set interpolation mode:
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Draw the new image:
        g.DrawImage(
            image,
            new Rectangle(          // Ziel
                0, 0,
                bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
            new Rectangle(          // Quelle
                0, 0,
                image.Width, image.Height),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Release the resources of the graphics:
        g.Dispose();

        // Release the resources of the origin image:
        image.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }
}
```